# Word 2010 - How to turn off all document updates from TFS

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

We have word 2010 document on TFS. When I get last version I always have so many balloons and caption that describe update
: [image]

and it drives me crazy. Can I "apply" all changes at once or just trun off this notification? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Review tab, the Accept button has a drop down with "Accept All Changes". In the Tracking section there are options to not show changes.

Comment: Thx man, I would lookin for it a long time :)